# fetch position of specific character in string in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Fetch the numeric part in the string such as ("bonus 20%") in crystal reports the o/p of the string should be like 10,20 or any numeric value.
After that, the numeric part has to divide by 100.

Comment: what's your question? Where's your code? What problem are you having with achieving your requirement?

Comment: for eg "Temp data 20%" i want the o/p to be 0.02 ie. the numeric text divided by 100.
data can be contain any text like "variable price 50% " o/p should be 0.50

Comment: That still isn't a _question_.

Comment: Thanks issue is resolved now

Comment: It took you a whole year? P.S. if you solved it you should write the solution as an Answer for others who might need help in future. You're allowed to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

If yourfield is always structured as in your example then following code will work

```
tonumber(split(split({@yourfield}," ")[2],"%")[1])/100
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it didn't worked for the data like
"10%"

Comment: Thanks for help but it didn't work for the data like
"10%"
"Temp year 30%"
"Variable year around 40%"
"current 20% year"

Answer (score 0):

numbervar strlen := len({@myfield});
numbervar i;
stringvar str;

For i := 1 To strLen Do
(
if isnumeric(mid({@myfield},i,1)) then str := str + mid({@myfield},i,1)
);
tonumber(str)/100

Comment: It Didn't workout for the above code all values converted into 2.02 +e type format

Comment: Sorry it does not work for you. I tested with the specific examples you provided.. "10%" "Temp year 30%" "Variable year around 40%" "current 20% year .. and it worked fine for me